# How type ç instead of ć?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard

I'm using a Microsoft Natural Ergonomic 4000 keyboard in Ubuntu 12.04.2, I choose `English US(alternative international)`, everything seems fine, but when I need to use the `ç` (I live in Brazil) cames `ć` at `Skype`.
How can I fix that ? In Brazil we never use this character `ć`, so I think to fix this I just need to exchange `ć` to `ç`.

Comment: @l1zard No, according to that page ç is code point 231 in ISO-8859-1. *Not* the same thing. ASCII is only defined for code points 0 through 127 inclusive.

Comment: you're sure right. correction foloows: i wanted to write 8859-1 in the first place. as descibed here for example torsten-horn.de/techdocs/ascii.htm it seems you want the 8859.1 charcter 231. The big quesion though is what one has to do to generate this.

Comment: How do you attempt to type ç when it comes out as ć?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling, I try `'` then `c` I get `ç` normally at `google chrome` but not at `skype` for example.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the compose key? When I <kbd>Right Shift</kbd>+<kbd>AltGr</kbd>, <kbd>'</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd>, I get ç.

For me this also works the other way around so try <kbd>c</kbd> then <kbd>'</kbd>

Comment: when I try `'` then `c` I get `ç` normally at `google chrome` but not at `skype` for example.

Comment: That's because Skype is a QT4 application and those follows slightly different rules. You can [unify the configuration](http://userbase.kde.org/ComposeKey#Persistent_Configuration) though.