# Compose key confusion concerning 'ç' and 'ć'

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, language, compose-key

I type in both French and Polish and therefore require both the 'ç' and 'ć' characters to be easy to enter. According to compose key documentation I find on the Internet, for example at http://hermit.org/Linux/ComposeKeys.html, `,+c = ç` and `'+c = ć`. **Yet, composing either of these results in 'ç'**.

I have my language set to U.S. English in UTF-8:

```
$ echo $LANG
en_US.UTF-8
$ echo $LANGUAGE
en
```

The following lines in my `/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8` corroborate that my compose key should not be behaving this way:

```
<dead_cedilla> <c>                  : "ç"   ccedilla # LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH CEDILLA
<Multi_key> <comma> <c>             : "ç"   ccedilla # LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH CEDILLA
<Multi_key> <cedilla> <c>           : "ç"   ccedilla # LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH CEDILLA

<dead_acute> <c>                    : "ć"   U0107 # LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH ACUTE
<Multi_key> <acute> <c>             : "ć"   U0107 # LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH ACUTE
<Multi_key> <apostrophe> <c>        : "ć"   U0107 # LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH ACUTE
```

I am running Ubuntu 12.04.

Can anyone reproduce this issue? If so, can anyone offer an explanation and/or a solution? Interestingly, in [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/631823/how-type-c-instead-of-c) the user is experiencing a similar but opposite issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Ubuntu (via GNOME) ignores locale-specific and customised compose-key configuration files in favour of a global, hard-coded configuration (because apparently hard-coding configuration info is a good idea now). You can overrule this genius decision by adding the following line to `~/.gnomerc`:

```
export GTK_IM_MODULE="xim"
```

Tested and working on Ubuntu 13.04 (so presumably it'll also work on 12.10) - more info [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey#Compose_key_sequences).

Comment: I avoid Gnome, but use many GTK apps. I've used `GTK_IM_MODULE=xim` for ages to stop such silliness. If you care to dig around in `[/usr/local]/etc/gtk-x.y/gtk.immodules` you *may* find `im-cedilla.so` is to blame. Now if only I could type a "ḉ"...

Comment: @mr.spuratic just add `<Multi_key> <comma> <apostrophe> <c>    : "ḉ"   U1E09 # LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH CEDILLA AND ACUTE` to your `~/.XCompose` file :-)